# How to publish roll/pitch data in Gmapping ？

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to publish the roll/pitch data in gmapping ？Thank you for your advices.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138221/how-to-publish-roll/pitch-data-in-gmapping-%EF%BC%9F/) by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-10**:
Do you want gmapping to use pitch/roll or do you want to get pitch/roll estimates out of gmapping. In either case: gmapping is set up  to be a 2D algorithm.

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-03-11**:
I use gmapping to create 2D map.But the ground is not flat.So I think maybe I need to publish roll and pitch and I want gmapping to use the data.I am confused about whether I should use a node to publish roll/pitch in some format like message or I only need to add pitch/roll to TF frames.

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-03-11**:
In other word, how can I let the gmapping know that there is roll/pitch data to use?Thank dornhege for your attention.Would you give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping itself can't make use of roll/pitch for pose estimation. What you can do however as a minimum is encode this information implicitly in the tf that you provide for odom->laser. Gmapping will transform laser messages to the odom frame.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-03-11**:
Your answer helps a lot. I will have a try.Thank you very much!